# split string with a certain character to form a path

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a string `abc_d_e75_f10_xyz_l_11` I want to split it so that I want to construct a string of an existing directory from this string to `cd` to it.

So in this example  `abc_d_e75_f10_xyz_l_11` I want to split using the `_` character where I want to write this command `cd /home/userA/abc/d_e75_f10` and neglect the rest of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

`echo "abc_d_e75_f10_xyz_l_11" | sed 's/_/\//' | cut -d "_" -f1-3`

This will replace the first `_` with `/` as well as trim the string.

Output:

`abc/d_e75_f10`

Comment: what does this do `-f1-3`?

Comment: `-f1-3` Means select only fields 1 to 3. `d` is field 1. `e75` is field 2, etc.

Comment: You could do this in a single sed command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bash shell's built-in string manipulation capabilities e.g.

```
$ var="abc_d_e75_f10_xyz_l_11"
$ echo "/home/userA/${var/_//}"
/home/userA/abc/d_e75_f10_xyz_l_11
```

Comment: But he wants to neglect everything after the fourth field `f10`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `sed`.

`sed` is a tool for performing search and replace operations on text.

In this case it seems like you want to replace the first occurrence of `_` with `/`.

This will do that:
    `echo "abc_d_e75_f10_xyz_l_11" | sed "s/_/\//"`

It looks wierd with the slashes but the idea is `"s/search/replace/"`. And `/` has to be escaped.

Comment: its giving this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'`  and I want to neglect everything after the fourth field `f10`.

Comment: Sorry forgot the quotes, updated my answer

Comment: want to neglect everything after the fourth field `f10`